# Is it a good idea to reuse the native code generated from React Native to continue building a native application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have an application developed with ReactNative but now my client wants to get rid of it and go native in Android and iOS, I got the native code that RN generates for both but it is strongly tided to RN libraries, is it a good idea to continue like this and try to re-use the code or it's better to start over from zero with native code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could re-use some of your code, but I would advice against this. It'll be easier to rewrite the whole app (2 times) than to try to decouple your code from react native's library.

Although, couldn't you convince your client to stay with RN? The problem that RN fix is the need to write your app twice, if you go on this path you'll take twice the time to achieve the same result, and you'll encounter some problems hard to debug if you are not comfortable working with Android and iOS' custom frameworks.

Comment: I do understand what you say (thank you for mentioning it) and I'm trying to convince my client to stay with RN, just wanted to have more information about this and more arguments to convince him. Thank you!